# Custom elements - how does "this" inside the constructor become the node we (re)define?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Let's assume I've defined a custom element like this:

```
class ArticleElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log(this); //the node we are (re)defining
    this.innerHTML = `
      <article>
        <h2>${this.getAttribute("title")}</h2>
        <p>${this.innerHTML}</p>
      </article>`;
  }
}

customElements.define("custom-article", ArticleElement);
```

My question is - how does `this` become the node we are (re)defining? Is this possible to be done in pure JavaScript without using native methods? Because if we execute the constructor with `new`, `this` points to the newly created object. I was trying to implement the `define` method like this:

```
function define(tag, CustomElement) {
  const elementsCollection = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
  Object.keys(elementsCollection).forEach((index) => {
    Object.setPrototypeOf(elementsCollection[index], CustomElement.prototype);
    elementsCollection[index].constructor();
  });
}

define("custom-article", ArticleElement);
```

But then remembered that the constructor of a class cannot be executed without new.

Here's my html file (if it even matters):

```
...
<custom-article title="Today is the day!">
   Today is a great day to go out and breathe some fresh air!
</custom-article>
...
```

Comment: `this` is a dynamic variable and what it actually points to is determined by mostly the call site. [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/9898651) is probably the best write up i've ever seen about `this`.